# Create a hidden AAD group

Tags: azure-active-directory

How do I create a hidden AAD group (number of users should be listed as 0) in a demo tenant?

I created a hidden group via

> New-UnifiedGroup -DisplayName "group-name" HiddenGroupMembershipEnabled

but I still see all the members in the group. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create **hidden** Azure AD Group, you can make use of below command:

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "Group_Name" -groupTypes "Unified" -Visibility "HiddenMembership" -SecurityEnabled $False -MailEnabled $True -MailNickname "mail_name"
```

Make sure to have **`AzureADPreview`** module installed before running the above command.

If you created Azure AD group with **"HiddenMembership"**, the **valid** users who can see that group members are:

- Group ***Owner***.
- Group ***Members***.
- Users who have ***admin*** roles.

Other than the above, if anyone tried to fetch the group members, they **won't** get any list of group members **(same as 0 users)**.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one Azure AD group with **"HiddenMembership"** and added few members using below script:

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "HiddenMem_Group" -Description "Hidden Members Group" -groupTypes "Unified" -Visibility "HiddenMembership" -SecurityEnabled $False -MailEnabled $True -MailNickname "hide_mem" 
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "GroupID" -RefObjectId "User_ObjectID"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please **note** that, the user who created group will be **Group Owner** of that group by ***default*** like below:

[image]

As **Testdemo** is **`Group Owner`**, he can get the list of group members using command like below:

```
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId <Group_ObjectID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When a normal user with **no admin roles** and **not a member** of that group runs the same command, he *won't* get any response **(same as 0 users)** like below:

```
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId <Group_ObjectID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[New-AzureADMSGroup (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0)